# mysqlimport,how to make a proper text load?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I have table created in this manner

```
CREATE TABLE mail
(
  t       DATETIME,    # when message was sent
  srcuser VARCHAR(8),  # sender (source user and host)
  srchost VARCHAR(20),
  dstuser VARCHAR(8),  # recipient (destination user and host)
  dsthost VARCHAR(20),
  size    BIGINT,      # message size in bytes
  INDEX (t)
);
```

When I latter performed this

```
mysqlimport -p --local cookbook mail.txt
Enter password: 
cookbook.mail: Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 30
```

I have now mail TABLE

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| t                   | srcuser | srchost | dstuser | dsthost | size    |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2014-05-11 10:15:08 | barb    | saturn  | tricia  | mars    |   58274 |
| 2014-05-12 12:48:13 | tricia  | mars    | gene    | venus   |  194925 |
| 2014-05-12 15:02:49 | phil    | mars    | phil    | saturn  |    1048 |
| 2014-05-12 18:59:18 | barb    | saturn  | tricia  | venus   |     271 |
| 2014-05-14 09:31:37 | gene    | venus   | barb    | mars    |    2291 |
| 2014-05-14 11:52:17 | phil    | mars    | tricia  | saturn  |    5781 |
| 2014-05-14 14:42:21 | barb    | venus   | barb    | venus   |   98151 |
| 2014-05-14 17:03:01 | tricia  | saturn  | phil    | venus   | 2394482 |
| 2014-05-15 07:17:48 | gene    | mars    | gene    | saturn  |    3824 |
| 2014-05-15 08:50:57 | phil    | venus   | phil    | venus   |     978 |
| 2014-05-15 10:25:52 | gene    | mars    | tricia  | saturn  |  998532 |
| 2014-05-15 17:35:31 | gene    | saturn  | gene    | mars    |    3856 |
| 2014-05-16 09:00:28 | gene    | venus   | barb    | mars    |     613 |
| 2014-05-16 23:04:19 | phil    | venus   | barb    | venus   |   10294 |
| 2014-05-19 12:49:23 | phil    | mars    | tricia  | saturn  |     873 |
| 2014-05-19 22:21:51 | gene    | saturn  | gene    | venus   |   23992 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |    NULL |
| 2014-05-11 10:15:08 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |    NULL |
| 2014-05-12 12:48:13 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |    NULL |
| 2014-05-12 15:02:49 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |    NULL |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |    NULL |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

This is my txt file

```
t                    srcuser  srchost  dstuser  dsthost    size 
2014-05-11 10:15:08  holmes   saturn   tricia   mars       99974 
2014-05-12 12:48:13  ines     mars     gene     venus      94902 
2014-05-12 15:02:49  phica    mars     phil     saturn     81048
```

What is wrong with my command line and with my text file?Why do I have all these `NULL`s?

Comment: When you see something like `cookbook.mail: Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 30` the first thing you should do is `show warnings;` (because this information will be gone when you execute another statement). And there you will probably find information why you have NULL values.

Comment: @fancyPants I am running my command from Linux shell,where should I put show warnings?

Comment: In the mysql client for example. Never used mysqlimport (as it's just another program for the actual command LOAD DATA INFILE) though, so I can't tell you how to do that with mysqlimport. It was just a general advice.

Comment: @fancyPants Ok,will try,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row of `NULL`s is for the header line of your file and the last one is because of an empty line at the end of the file.

The three inner rows have only the `t` value properly set because MySQL expects the values to be separated by comma in the input file and they are separated by something else (`tab` character, I guess) in the input file.

Because it cannot find the separator it thinks the input file contains only one column (`t`) and fills the rest with `NULL`.

You can provide the information needed by `mysqlimport` to successfully parse your file:

- `--ignore-lines 1` -- to ignore the header row;
- `--fields-terminated-by '\t'` -- I assume the values are separated by `tab` in your file;
- the empty line at the end of the input file can be manually removed using a text editor.

The command line is:

```
mysqlimport -p --local --ignore-lines 1 --fields-terminated-by '\t' cookbook mail.txt
```

Read more about [`mysqlimport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html).